# pull users ids where the have 2 different roles assigned. Repeat userid in the output

Tags: sql, multiple-conditions

I have data that shows 2 different roles assigned to the same userid.  I want to extract only users that have more than one role assigned and get the user id and name of multiple roles in output.
Output would be:

```
user id   role
--------------------
12345     initiator 
12345     approver
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle ? https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Please show the table DDL and example table data, not just the expected result.  Also read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It will be something like this

```
select user_id as user_id, role from users a
inner join (
  select user_id as user from users
  group by user_id having count(role) > 1
) b on a.user_id=b.user
```

[Fiddle Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fwEs7H2N66XfJ3aE29w9sX/0)